# Eclipse, Git - Keyboard Shortcut, How to use?

Tags: eclipse, git

What keyboard shortcut is commit bound to here (see image below)? (alternatively, how do I enter a # without using shift?).

I know how to update shortcuts in eclipse, but it is already bound to this default, and I'd prefer to just use that. :)

[image]

Comment: What I do is: <Option-Key>, E, C

Comment: I don't quite understand...is that on Mac?

Comment: No, the key between Alt-Gr and Right-Ctrl

Comment: oooooo to bring up the right-click menu.  Got it!  That works. :)

Comment: In Windows 7, I just press "Ctrl+Shift+3". It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the **poke** from @Evan commenting on the question.

In Juno, ctrl+shift+3 (ie. you are doing literally ctrl+#) does NOT work.
(which, is why this was opened, since the obvious combination didn't seem to do the trick.).

However!
I have tested now in Kepler and Luna, and the shortcut does work.
So, I am considering this closed.

Comment: Also, to clarify, this seems to be related to the git shortcuts not being activated by default in the command group availability, mentioned earlier by @Janning

Answer (score 16):

The keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> only works for me after activating command group in `Window > Customize Perspective > Command Groups Availability > Git`

Comment: Solved the problem for me, why doesn't eclipse do this for you!

Comment: Unfortunately this has the side effect of adding a git toolbar. But this can be disabled with `Window > Customize Perspective > Tool Bar Visibility > Git`. Useful if you don't have lots of screen space.

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes what happens is that the shortcut it s not binded to a key.

So to bind the shortcut with a key you have to go (as @Janning and @Nateowami said):`Window > Customize Perspective > Tool Bar Visibility > Git`

After that if you select `Git` in `Available command groups` go to the `Toolbar details` (as in picture):
[image: Key bind for eclipse shortcut]

There you have to select `key bindings` and complete the binding:
[image: complete key bind]

That should put a bind to your shortcut. Otherway is just searching on `Windows > Preferences` 
[image: key bind in preferences]

Answer (score 2):

Buy another keyboard with a different keyboard layout than your current one (or just switch your keyboard layout in the OS).

Judging from your profile, you might be using a [Canadian Multilangual Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Canadian) keyboard. The egit developers are probably used to the standard English or German layouts (looking at the core committers), where <kbd>#</kbd> can be accessed without <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Comment: Might I ask, why this answer was downvoted? I believe it very exactly describes the reasons behind your problem, even if the suggested solution has large side effects.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the Staging View for committing, it's much more convenient. Find it using Ctrl+3 (or Command+3 on OS X) and typing "Staging View". Also see the [user guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Git_Staging_View).

In EGit 2.1, it's now also possible to commit in the Staging view when you are finished writing the commit message, using **Ctrl+Enter** (or **Command+Enter** on OS X). (That was implemented in [bug 382936](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382936).)

Comment: hmmmm, that might be a good alternate approach.  I will see how it works.