# Egit - commit message shortcut key not working

Tags: eclipse, egit

I've installed Egit on my Eclipse Kepler.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd>,the commit message window doesn't open.

I've checked [Eclipse, Git - Keyboard Shortcut, How to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674585/eclipse-git-keyboard-shortcut-how-to-use)

> The keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> only works for me after activating command group in Window > Customize Perspective > Command Groups Availability > Git

But still commit message window isn't opening.

Comment: Cmon, just use right click -> commit, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my fault.

`3` and `#` is in same key in keyboard.

Now its working when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>